# delete an item from a NSMutableArray for a specific key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

I am trying to figure out how to delete one item from this NSMutableArray that I am using for a sectioned table. This is how I build the data source:

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *appleComputers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook Pro",nil];
NSDictionary *appleComputersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:appleComputers forKey:@"Computers"];

NSArray *otherComputers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HP", @"Dell", @"Windows", nil];
NSDictionary *otherComputersDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:otherComputers forKey:@"Computers"];

[listOfItems addObject:appleComputersDict];
[listOfItems addObject:otherComputersDict];
```

I am trying to figure out how to delete, say "iPod" from this array? I have tried many things, among them the one below, but nothing worked.

```
    [listOfItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

(problem here is that there is no reference for the actual section...)

Thanks!

UPDATE: This is where I delete the row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


    NSMutableArray * section = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];    
    [section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tblSimpleTable reloadData];

} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

   // some code...
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're using a dictionary... doesn't seem like you need one. How about just an array of arrays?

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray * appleComputers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook Pro",nil];
[listOfItems addObject:appleComputers];

NSMutableArray * otherComputers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"HP", @"Dell", @"Windows", nil];
[listOfItems addObject:otherComputers];
```

then

```
NSMutableArray * section = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];    
[section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Even if you *do* need to use the dictionaries, it's still not a big deal... just use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` for your `appleComputers` or `otherComputers` and do this:

```
NSDictionary * section = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSMutableArray * sectionComputers = [section objectForKey:@"Computers"];    
[sectionComputers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: It's a good start, but I this solution doesnt update my original data source, rather it only creates a new array without the removed item.

Comment: It doesn't create a new array at all. It updates the array you initially added to the list. If you have an "original data source" other than the one you illustrated in the sample code with static items, perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: I do not. listOfItems is the only one. But in your code, you are creating "section" out of listOfItems, then remove an object from "section" which is a subset of listOfItems, and not part of it anymore. so listOfItems is not being updated.

Comment: I think you're confused. I'm not *creating* `section` out of `listOfItems`, I'm simply getting a reference to it. If you're using this for a `UITableView`, which I suspect you are, make sure you call `reloadData` on the table. Also, keep `listOfItems` at the class level (as a property/ivar) and release it in dealloc.

Comment: +1 I see your point. Well, it still crashes here: [section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; I have updated my question with the method where I am deleting the row is thats of any help.

Comment: @TommyG let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2922/discussion-between-steve-and-tommyg)

Comment: I did get your error message in the chat (sorry, I left the computer). You're calling "removeObjectAtIndex" on a Dictionary. You can't do that. If you're still using a dictionary, you'll have to change your code to use my second example, not the first one. In the second example, I show how to retrieve the dictionary, then retrieve the array in the dictionary stored under the "Computers" key.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you'd remove all 'iPod' entries like this (note changes to mutable collections):

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *appleComputers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPod",@"MacBook",@"MacBook Pro",nil];
NSMutableDictionary *appleComputersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:appleComputers forKey:@"Computers"];

NSMutableArray *otherComputers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"HP", @"Dell", @"Windows", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *otherComputersDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:otherComputers forKey:@"Computers"];

[listOfItems addObject:appleComputersDict];
[listOfItems addObject:otherComputersDict];

...

for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in listOfItems) {
    [dict objectForKey:@"Computers" removeObject:@"iPod"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [array removeObject:@"iPod"]?

Comment: Doesnt work - what if I have multiple "iPod"s? I will need to use the indexpath property for reference. Thanks though.